# Build work space error occur?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

When i checkout the project from SVN after complete the half half the process it shows **build work space error occur**. please any one help me why it's come.

Comment: [build work space error occur](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=build+work+space+error+occur&oq=build+work+space+error+occur&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Basically my eclipse is working when i checkout project from SVN at the time this is shown.

Comment: could you please post the complete error

Comment: If it's an Eclipse error that disappears after cleaning the project and refreshing (F5), just ignore it. Eclipse sees that the files on disk are changed, but does not reload them (unlike Idea).

Comment: Thank u guys i got the my mistake in my SVN  i miss the project.properties file. That why it's show the error

Answer (score 1):

Select the project properties -> android, here change the target API and restart the eclipse. It worked for me.